# Subtraction rule of Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given that $f_n\in L^+$, $f_n$ converges decreasingly to $f$ pointwise, and $\int f_1 <\infty$. Show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n = \int f$.

This is an exercise (Folland 1.15). I observe $f_1 - f_n$ converge increasingly to $f_1-f$ pointwise since $f_n$ converges decreasingly to $f$. Then using Monotone Convergence Theorem, I got $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int (f_1 - f_n) = \int (f_1 - f)$.

The left-hand side equals to $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\int f_1 - \int f_n )=  \int f_1 - \lim_{n\to \infty}\int f_n$. The right-hand side equals to $\int f_1 - \int f$. Since $int f_1 < \infty$, we can subtract it from both side, therefor obtain $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n = \int f$.

But when I check my answer with the solution online, it seems incorrect to directly conclude that $\int (f_1 - f_n) = \int f_1 - \int f_n $, and I don't understand why. The solution first proved that $\int (f_1 - f_n)<\infty$, and then split into $\int f_1 - \int f_n $.

Therefore my question is, in general, if I have $f_1, f_2\in L^+$, do I have have to make sure $\int (f_1-f_2) < \infty$ before stating $\int (f_1-f_2) = \int f_1- \int f_2$?

I am pretty sure that if I have $f_1, f_2\in L^+$, then $\int (f_1+f_2) = \int f_1+ \int f_2$ without the assumption that $(f_1+f_2) < \infty$. Here is the proof:

I know operation holds for any two simple functions (Folland proposition 2.13), and to apply it in general functions we just pick two sequences, say $\{\phi_j\}, \{\psi_j\}$ of simple functions, to approximate $f_1, f_2$ respectively. Then $\int(f_1+f_2)=\lim \int (\phi_j+\psi_j)  =\lim \int \phi_j+ \lim \int \psi_j  =  \int f_1 + \int f_2$. '

However it seems I need to be very carful when dealing with subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you need to be careful in general, but here the equality $\int(f_1 - f_n) = \int f_1 - \int f_n$ is justified because both $f_1$ and $f_n$ are integrable. In general, we have $\int(f + g) = \int f + \int g$ if either both $f, g \in L^+$ or both $f, g$ are integrable, i.e. $\int |f| < \infty$ and $\int |g| < \infty$.